# Is this answer really of very poor quality in Late Answers review audit?

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits

The screenshot below is from an answer from the Late Answers Review Queue audit that I failed to pass. (This is my first fail ever, after some 500+ reviews and I take this seriously.)

The answer is not a verbose one indeed, but still gives a short explanation/context and the bash command to (correctly) answer the original question.
The "@Thomas" part at the beginning? Yes, that *could be* a trace of a comment, but it is not. It is not the luckiest thing to start an answer with that, but as *I payed attention*, I saw the answer in that post with a bit of personal flavor.

[image: Late Answers Review Audit fail]

The Original Post is here: [Adding products showing out of stock magento 2.0.7 version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38054164/adding-products-showing-out-of-stock-magento-2-0-7-version),
and here is the link to the review: https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/18340557

According to that thread, the answer used in the audit was indeed correct, and apparently provided extra information with the bash command, which is an important part of the solution.
Obviously as the answer above was part of an audit, it was already deleted, but as a result of that deletion, the OP does not have a “complete answer” now.

The only possible reason I can think of that lead to deletion was that there is another –one liner– answer from the OP that *mentions* the solution.

So my question is, was this really a very poor quality answer?

Comment: Yeah, it was a wrong deletion by the review queue. I've undeleted the answer and edited out the comment part. If you see any more answers like that which have been wrongly deleted, flag that post (if 10k+), or flag the question (10k-) for moderator attention and inform us. (Something like, "This post here <link to answer>, has been wrongly deleted by the low quality posts queue here <link to review>" would be fine)

Comment: Thanks! By any chance, does this also mean that my review audit history is clean now, or I still have that stigma?

Comment: You'll still have it in your history, but it won't become a bad audit for others. Think of yourself as a soldier, who took a bullet to save others. (Also, I'm bad at analogies)

Comment: @BhargavRao when do we fix the defective turret AI that keeps shooting our soldiers?

Comment: Welcome to the club. I had [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/18274039). It _might_ be obvious why was bad answer if you open the link and browse all other answers.

Comment: @JohnDvorak In 6-8 weeks.

Comment: Why 6-8 weeks ?

Comment: @Asif.Ali in case you really don't know: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19514/225760

Comment: "I faced same issue and re-indexing solved my problem": that's poorly worded. I would have robo-voted to delete ... and would have passed the audit :)

Comment: @Jean, Robo-voting to delete was the reason for *creating* that audit in the first place.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I think your problem is that you don't realize the difference between "very poor quality" and "poor quality." Let that sink in.

Comment: I wouldn't call that "my problem", mind.

Comment: @BhargavRao Sorry to bother you this way, but I cannot flag a question –as you suggested– that was deleted and used in an audit. I've run into an audit (triage this time) with this question: https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/18579861. Is it really nonsense? Thanks!

Comment: Oops, @dferenc, that's similar to this incident https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/361837/what-exactly-is-wrong-with-this-deleted-question, I've informed the mod involved in that.

Comment: Thanks @BhargavRao! I've another one from earlier, just in case it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/18551231.

Comment: Done, cleared that audit as well.