# What exactly is wrong with this deleted question?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions, triage

As I was going through my Triage daily queue in Stack Overflow, I got to this question:

[image]

I have **no experience** with 'build system' or 'ninja' so I can't be sure, but to me it looked like a fair question (as far as I can tell). Also, there are no links, which I know are sometimes abused.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/18494327) is the question, from my triage history.

So why was it deleted by Community, that too for being 'Offensive/Span'. Isn't that reserved for actual advertisements (e.g. games) or spam (e.g. random nonsense)?

Comment: I've no idea why it was flag-deleted a spam. If there's something hidden in there, it's extremely non-obvious. And the track record shows that - it's been selected as an audit 19 times and only 3 have passed. I cleared the spam flag, but will leave an answer to a moderator who might know why it was deleted in the first place.

Comment: MAYBE the fact the user has been deleted means something? But yeah, it definitely feels like an audit I would have flunked as well

Comment: IIRC if a post is deleted as spam or offensive by community with only one downvote, that means a mod flagged it as spam (which instantly marks the flag helpful and deletes the content. We could guess reasons all day but without knowing which mod flagged it as spam and why they did so, it is impossible to say. That said, invalidating the spam flag should remove the post as an audit, which I think is a fairly clear choice in this situation.

Comment: Its a test question to you & your concentration on each action. Giving options to check questions will help in improving Stack. There will be all type of questions, If its an unknown topic please 'skip' that one. If you push other options stack system considers you as a person having knowledge on this topics & mark you Failed on the test. After that test the question will not be reached because its a test to you review, not a real scenario question.

Comment: @Sinto Yes actually my response of 'Requires editing' was wrong, I should've skipped it.

Comment: @animuson probably because it was a spam seed?

Comment: It could be that the code offered is nonsense, but it looks reasonable.

Comment: I am beginning to understand why StackOverflow is such a mess.   Poor quality answers upvoted due to popularity.  Authoritative answers downvoted due to lack of popularity.  Moderators deleted good answers.  And now, robots that do more than they are intended for.  Yikes.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When I originally commented here and cleared the spam flag, I didn't realize there was a wider problem at hand.

There was actually a handful of posts involved here - all from a select few users that were clearly abusing the system by posting very low-quality questions to immediately answer them, and even copy-pasting existing questions and answers from elsewhere on Stack Overflow. All of these posts definitely should have been deleted, but they are far from the definition of spam and the use of that flag was somewhat inappropriate.

I can understand what the moderator was thinking and wanting to block the users from continuing their behavior, but using the wrong flag type to achieve one goal with other annoying side-effects isn't usually the best course of action. I've gone through most of the posts and cleared the spam flags off of them so that the majority of the posts will no longer be selected as review audits that pretty much everyone fails because it's not at all clear what the problem was.

We've pointed this out to the moderator team and hopefully this problem will not repeat - we should always be careful of where we use spam and abusive flags on posts.

Answer (score -9):

My only guesses are:
A) The user posting the question was deleted
B) The code that was posted in the question is not in code wrappers for SO formatting.
C) Mix of those 2, plus if you try and read it from a regex standpoint (which i would assume has some role to play in what posts are flagged for mods to take a look at, maybe im wrong!) theres not a lot of pure substance there in the sense of typical keywords for typical questions.

All just absolute guesses - I in no way work for SO, am a mod, or have any factual knowledge of how this is set up on their end - just throwing my assumptions out to see if it may help someone.

Comment: Well that would still not count as spam.