# Can this review audit answer be undeleted?

Tags: discussion, support, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

I failed [this review audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/18507580) because the post was deleted as spam or offensive. The user account is deleted as well, so I don't dispute that *something* fishy was going on, but I don't see a problem with this particular post.

> Here is an Awk script that does it:
>
> ```
> #!/usr/bin/awk -f
> BEGIN {
>  if (ARGC != 2) {
>    print "peri.awk <URL>"
>    exit 1
> }
> RS = ">"
> FS = "\42"
> while ("curl " ARGV[1] | getline) {
>   if (/og:url/) {
>     print $6
>   }
>  }
> }
> ```
>
> Result:
>
> https://www.pscp.tv/QueeGualaa/1OwxWMEldYNGQ

The answer does have a URL in it, but the question is about resolving URLs, and the URLs in the question and answer both go to the same site. In addition to that, the OP left the following comment on this (the only) answer:

> I added "-s" to curl in your script because of that download stats showing up, and that works perfectly! Thanks – Paul G. Dec 17 '17 at 19:57

Since it appears to answer the question, can that one answer from this user be undeleted so it will no longer be used as a review audit?

Alternatively, if the target of the URL is the problem, should the question be removed as well?

Comment: Can the question/answer be flagged because of the content at the other end of the link?

Comment: Because I could understand that the "NO ***** ALLOWED" on that page would be enough reason to flag/delete that. It's true that the question should be flagged as well, but that's a separate issue.

Comment: @yivi Good question. Now that I've followed the link, I can see how that content is at least borderline offensive.

Comment: But I'd say that following the links to check for spam or other questionable content would be part of the due diligence expected in audits, wouldn't it?

Comment: @yivi It's formatted as code in the review, so it's not a URL you can click on to follow.

Comment: Offensive? I just saw a dude driving and one with a guitar ... may be random. Anyway, if this question can be improved by removing the links (if the links are the issue), then we can edit both posts.

Comment: [This](https://imgur.com/a/ZoYBb) is what I see when I follow that link. I would find it reason enough to flag a post, but maybe it's just me.

Comment: @yivi Oh, I should mention that I visited the main site and not the linked page ^^. Well yes, that should be changed to a different site. If that's not possible (maybe because no other sub-site acts like this one regarding the URL redirect), then this Q&A can't be saved (imo).

Comment: @Tom Offensive content should be flagged, not edited out.

Comment: @yivi Is a bare URL offensive content, though? Neither question nor answer has it formatted as a clickable link.

Comment: @yivi I disagree in this context. The question is about a URL redirect and OP may have used the URL for either a stream (s)he likes or their own stream. Thus the text written on that page may not have been there when the question was asked and I also don't believe that this question was asked to promote that text on the other site.

Comment: @Bill, personally, I find the presence of the link, even without the anchor tag, offensive enough. But I can accept that maybe I'm too thin skinned.

Comment: I would opt for removing the question in this case despite the url itself not being offensive, you have to *test*  that url. Alternatively, find a proper url that exhibits the same behavior.

Comment: @yivi You're right that the current content of the linked site is BS and we don't want that link, but I still would try to find a different link instead (like rene wrote), rather then deleting the whole Q&A, because I still believe that the current content wasn't there then the question was asked, so I wouldn't punish OP for that.

Comment: I would delete the question as well, and I flagged it. But that logically goes  against the "undelete this audit".

Comment: @Tom I think that if you are going to post an outgoing link, you should do it wisely, and the onus is on you if that said link changes.

Comment: @yivi I hadn't followed the URL until after my edit. Either outcome is ok with me after seeing the page it links to.

Comment: Mmm... awk answer to android tagged question seems like that answer should have been deleted anyways. Wait, why it is that tagged android anyways?

Comment: Even when ignoring the url and it's content, is the answer really high quality enough to warrant a undeletion? I'm not an expert in that area, but the answer needs at least some details on how it solves the problem. Why was awk choosen?

Comment: Errm, I was not the mod who single spam destroyed that, but looking at it and the other [similar incident](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/361837/what-exactly-is-wrong-with-this-deleted-question), I did some background checks, and found out the reason why it was nuked as spam. It was from an account (of a particular troll user) which was trying to add more spam links after a few legit answers. I'd have just nuked the account, instead of spam flagging that and then nuking it.  I unlocked and undeleted the answer, but deleted the post as a whole because of the r/a links.

Comment: @Braiam I think it was the android tag that was in error. The OP asked for a solution using standard Linux command line tools.

Comment: @BhargavRao Thank you for the clarification, and for removing the post from the review audit queue.

Comment: @BhargavRao that sounds like a plausible explanation. Maybe ping the mod that handled the issue?

Comment: Yep, @Braiam, I've informed them of this post.